LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref. (if use xwatermark package)
I need to insert a watermark over the PDF text. However, I am facing the error

LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref

when I use the command
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III, pdfversion=2}} 

Could you please advise on how to resolve the error.
My MWE is below
\DocumentMetadata{testphase={phase-III,pdfversion = 2}}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\newwatermark*[allpages,color=blue,fontsize=30pt,angle=45]{Sample WaterMark Text Here}

\begin{document}

\section{H1-1 section Sample}
A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.
A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.

A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.
A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.A simple table with names, ages, and cities.


\end{document}


do not use the xwatermark package. It loads the catoptions package and that is incompatible with a current LaTeX. See also the description in the catalog: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xwatermark

@murugananbu You don't need any special packages to add a watermark, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724404/36296
